# Lua — If error in function, then do something

Tags: lua

I feel like this should be simple, but can't seem to solve it. I have a function in Lua that's designed to validate a confirm code in a survey. Basically, if the ID is valid, then we can grab lots of data from that code, but if it's not a valid code, the script will break because it'll be populating nil values.

So, I basically need an error check — if the function can run properly, then run it. If it can't then I need to ask for a new code.

I've tried using pcall which feels like is exactly for this. I'm working off the Lua documentation:

```
   if pcall(foo) then
      -- no errors while running `foo'
      ...
    else
      -- `foo' raised an error: take appropriate actions
      ...
    end
```

On my end, that means I have a function:

```
function populate()

 ... doing lots here to unencrypt and parse the ID someone gives and populate variables

end
```

Then I'm running the follwing:

```
if pcall(populate) then
  print('no errors!') -- Just printing as a test, if there's no error, I'll run the script
  else
  print('Oh snap theres an error!) -- I'll change this to ask the user for a valid ID and then try again
end
```

What am I missing? I know it's going to be simple. But the last part of my code always returns the "Oh snap..." no matter what.

Thanks in advance, I have a super complex code running that I was able to build from just reading responses to other questions, but can't seem to get this simple part to work. Entirely possible I'm missing the point of pcall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect?
If i am unsure what happen or which return value i should use for another condition i normally test/check in Lua Standalone...

```
€ lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> pcall(string.gsub,'foo','%l','bar') -- Check for lowercases
true    barbarbar   3
> pcall(string.gsub,'foo','%u','bar') -- Check for uppercases
true    foo 0
> -- In this case i have to use maybe the third return value to decide what to do?
> -- OK -- Lets go...
> a, b, c = pcall(string.gsub,'foo','%u','bar') -- Check for uppercases
> if a and c == 0 then print('Only Kiddies here!') return false end
Only Kiddies here!
false
>
```

Comment: Totally makes sense what you're doing above — so am I wrong in understanding that pcall can check to see if a function can run correctly without errors?

Comment: It depends on and that shows above example what the calling function is returning or what is expected as an error. ```string.gsub()``` raises an error when called without or wrong arguments. Not if it found nothing. Therefore pcall say: true

Comment: Really appreciate the help. I'm thinking maybe then pcall isn't what I'm looking for? I'm just looking for a simple way to not run a function if there's an error in it and instead do something else. Appreciate the help and please let me know if I'm misunderstanding and your code above will do that. Thanks again.

Comment: Welp, your answer actually did solve my problem. The issue was in the ordering of operations — I was calling the error check before I was defining the function. [head slap.] Thanks again for the time!